# ggplot for linear-log regression model?

Tags: r

How do I plot a log linear model in R?
Currently, I am doing this but am not sure if it's the right/efficient way:

```
data(food)
model1 <- lm(food_exp~log(income), data = food)
temp_var <- predict(model1, interval="confidence")
new_df <- cbind(food, temp_var)
head(new_df)
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = income, y = food_exp))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=lwr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=upr), color = "red", linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_smooth(aes(y = fit), color = "blue")+
  theme_economist()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use geom_smooth and putting your formula directly in. It should yield the same as your fit (which you can check by also plotting that)

```r
ggplot(new_df, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(aes(y=fit), color="red") + #your original fit
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~log(x)) #ggplot fit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't car about extracting the parameters and just want the plot, you can plot directly in ggplot2.

Some fake data for plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(454)
income <- VGAM::rpareto(n = 100, scale = 20, shape = 2)*1000
food_exp <- rnorm(100, income*.3+.1, 3)

food <- data.frame(income, food_exp)
```

Now within ggplot2, use the `geom_smooth` function and specify that you want a linear model. Additionally, you can directly transform the income in the `aes` argument:

```
ggplot(food, aes(x = log(income), y = food_exp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(
    title = "Log Linear Model Food Expense as a Function of Log(income)",
    x = "Log(Income)",
    y = "Food Expenses"
  )
```

[image: Desired graph of log of income vs expenses]

This will work for confidence intervals, but adding prediction intervals, you'll need to do what you did earlier with fitting the model, generating the prediction intervals.

Comment: But I don't want the x axis to be logarithmic